# How to properly build models in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement a photo gallery in my project. in the django rest framework I want the output to be:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "owner": {
            "username": "drw",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/default.png",
        },
        "gallery": {
            "id": 4,
            "project_gallery": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/2022/8/9/drw/616da7a24f6856fab5dac79a_360_IT_Check_-_October_18th_2021_wUvme58.png",
                    "thumbnail": null,
                    "user": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/2022/8/9/drw/Adapta-KDE-theme_vdDo0PO.webp",
                    "thumbnail": null,
                    "user": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/2022/8/9/drw/Adapta-KDE-theme_ghZHmGF.webp",
                    "thumbnail": null,
                    "user": 1
                }
            ],
            "project_gallery_name": "Testowo"
        },
        "likes": [],
        "category": "ca1",
        "uuid": "30065e4d-3674-4f01-9861-307fe27ede13",
        "project_name": "Testowo",
        "comments": null
    }
]
```

I do not know if I am doing well with manytomany.

```
class ImagesForGallery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'User: {} || Image: {}'.format(self.user, self.image)

class GalleryProject(models.Model):
    project_gallery_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    project_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(ImagesForGallery, blank=True, related_name='project_gallery')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.project_gallery_name)
```

if i want an output like above then should i use many to many or foreginkey?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achive. If every instance from ImagesForGallery belong to only one GalleryProject you should use `models.ForeignKey` inside ImagesForGallery. But if you want that every model could belong to more then one GalleryProject you wrote this correct.
Read about [model relationship in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/)

Also to achive this output you need to create [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).